# put the name of textarea in document.form (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, document

I need to put a textarea name into document.form variable, put the code and I'll try to explain better

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>

<meta name="description" content="" />

    <meta charset='iso-8859-1'>
<script type="text/javascript">

function initializeVar(option1,option2,number){

    var v = document.forms['variables'];
    var txtAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    var txtareaname = txtAreas[0].name

    if(option1.checked)
    {
    for (var i=0;i<number.value;i++)
         v.id.value = 'N' + v.id.value;
    }
}
</script>   
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="index.html">Test</a></div>
    &nbsp;

  <ul>

    <li><a href="check.html">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>

<form action="createtxt.php" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data" name="variables">
<p>Enter sequence:  
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="n"> N
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="a"> A
<input name="number" type="number" placeholder="write a number" />
<button type="button" onclick=initializeVar(this,option1,option2,number)>Create it!</button>

<textarea id="id" name="id" rows="7" cols="60"></textarea>

<p>Enter sequence: </p> 
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="n"> N
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="a"> A
<input name="number" type="number" placeholder="write a number" />
<button type="button" onclick=initializeVar(this,option1,option2,number)>Create it!</button>
<textarea id="srna" name="srna" rows="7" cols="60"></textarea>

<p><input type="submit" value="Check form"> 
   <input type="reset" value="Delete all"></p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I would like to do, v.txtareaname.value instead of v.id.value, because I would like to use the same function for some textareas and not to do one function each textarea. I hope that you understood me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide code that is closer to what you are trying to accomplish. As it stands, v refers to a form element, so "v.id.value" is meaningless. I suspect you are intending to access one of the textareas based on the value of "i" in the loop, but that is not what is going to happen. Would be happy to try to address your question if you can provide clearer code.

Comment: I changed my first question, I hope that now you can help me and it's more clear to understand